# java Failed to create new file in windows 7?

Tags: java, io, java-io

I 'm trying to create new file in windows 7 using

```
file.createNewFile()
```

but the file is not created and I got the following exception

```
Message:
The system cannot find the path specified
Stack Trace:
[java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified,
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method),
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883),
    at com.mercury.mtf.actions.file.CreateEmptyFileTask.execute(CreateEmptyFileTask.java:56),
    at com.mercury.mtf.actions.file.CreateEmptyFileAction.execute(CreateEmptyFileAction.java:42),
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.AbstractAction.run(AbstractAction.java:50),
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.Unit.runUnitAction(Unit.java:347),
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.Unit.executeUnitAction(Unit.java:176),
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.Unit.run(Unit.java:121),
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.execution.DefaultUnitExecutor.call(DefaultUnitExecutor.java:24),
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303),
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138),
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98),
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:207),
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886),
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908),
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)]
```

I'm sure that the path exists, but I realized that the folder marked as read only. I tried to remove the read only flag but I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your path separator character is proper.. You can use single forward slash or double back slashes. For example,

```
File f = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\thandasoru\\My Documents\\temp.txt");
f.createNewFile();
```

Comment: This could be solved using `File.separator` or `File.separatorChar`. BTW, these two static final fields do not follow Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: ah, exactly! I forgot there is File.separatorChar property. the above mentioned code is dirty fix I'd say ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the file is temporary you can use this function and you can forget all permissions problems:

```
File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `File newFile=new File(folderName+chipItems[i]);` rather than using   `File newFile=new File(folderName+chipItems[i], "w");`. That will be OK. Avoid File Mode when you like to give functionality like Unix touch command.